# When pyCharm is running, I can't right click it to add it to taskbar

Tags: pycharm

I have pyCharm running, but the only options I get when I right click it on the left is "All Windows," and "Quit."

I'd like to add it to my taskbar because it vanishes out of thin air after I close it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once Pycharm Loads Navigate to the tools menu and select the option 'Create desktop entry'.It will prompt you about adding a desktop entry for all users. After this step, close the application. Now, you can access Pycharm directly from your applications menu.

Comment: Thanks so much! Perfect. :)

Comment: You are Welcome!